# Cannot reference Java annotation in Scala class

Tags: java, scala, annotations

I have a scala class that's giving the compiler error

```
error: expected start of definition
Hello.scala:23: error: expected start of definition
class Hello extends Baz {
```

I believe the cause is due to an annotation that I reference from a precompiled java library.  A simplified version of the scala code is a follows:

```
import com.xx.{
  Bar,
  Baz
}

@Bar(value = "XX", description = "xx")

class Foo extends Baz {
}
```

The java code is:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Bar {

  String value() default "";
  String description() default "";
}
```

I'm using Scala 2.10.3. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to provide code that is possible at least to compile. Is it Hello or Foo that is causing the problem? What is the definition of Baz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall not put empty line between annotation and class definition, this one should work:

```
import com.xx.{Bar,Baz}

@Bar(value = "XX", description = "xx")
class Foo extends Baz {
}
```